# Wrong number of lines/ticks on d3 bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a simple d3 bar chart and I'm trying to draw horizontal lines in the background.

The bars on the chart represent percentages, with a full-height bar being 100%. I want to show 4 bars, at 25%, 50%, 75% and 100% levels. But if I do this:

```
svg.selectAll('.rule')
    .data(y.ticks(4))
.enter().append('line')
    .attr('class', 'rule')
    .attr('x1', 0)
    .attr('x2', width)
    .attr('y1', y)
    .attr('y2', y);
```

then the `y.ticks(4)` shows 5 lines. If I change it to `3` I get 2 lines. If I change it to `5` then I still get 5 lines. [Here's an example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philgyford/TVNuZ/3/).

Also, at the end of that script, I tried adding a y-axis, but it only displays horizontally - how do I get it to appear vertically? This seems to Just Work in all the examples I've seen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The param of the `ticks()` method of `d3.scale.linear()` is just a hint. The method uses this as an approximation, but it will pick "pretty" values. (see here: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-linear_ticks)

If you want to set the values explicitly, you need to instantiate a `d3.svg.axis()` and use `axis.tickValues()` (like you did further down).

Regarding your 2nd question. The axis has a default orientation (which you're seeing), for using as a horizontal, X axis. You need to call `.orient("left")` or `.orient("right")` to get a vertical axis. Note, if you use "left" orientation, you won't actually see an axis, bc its numbers will run off the left edge of the SVG and get cropped. So it's a good idea in general to add some padding to the SVG and shift all your graphics within it. If you use "right" orientation you'll see the numbers, but typically in this case you'd translate the axis to the right side of the graph.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you - with a bit of fiddling, and reading of [this example](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/adding-grid-lines-to-d3js-graph.html), I got it [all working nicely](http://jsfiddle.net/philgyford/TVNuZ/6/).

Comment: Nice, it looks good. I did noticed though that your `.axis` CSS style has a stroke applied to it. As a result, everything inside the axis –– including the tick labels' font –– gets a stroke. It gives the text a unique look, but I'm not sure it was intentional.

Comment: Oh yes - I wondered why that looked odd but didn't investigate. [Fixed it now](http://jsfiddle.net/philgyford/TVNuZ/7/), thanks.